# I'm getting error, `req.redirect` is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, backend

I'm newbie to the node.

I'm getting following error,

```
TypeError: req.redirect is not a function
    at Post.create (/var/www/html/node_blog/index.js:40:7)
    at /var/www/html/node_blog/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:276:16
    at Function.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_blog/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4798:21)(/var/www/html/node_blog/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:486:7)
    at /var/www/html/node_blog/node_modules/kareem/index.js:315:21
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at /var/www/html/node_blog/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4781:13
    at /var/www/html/node_blog/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:276:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Following is my code

```
app.post('/post/save', (req, res) => {
    Post.create(req.body, (err, post) => {
        req.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Comment: redirect is defined on res not on req so you should be using something like this:

`app.post('/post/save', (req, res) => {
    Post.create(req.body, (err, post) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following line

```
  Post.create(req.body, (err, post) => {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use redirect on `response` object. Redirect method is defined in response object.

Request object contains the information of the client request.
And the response is used to send the response to client. Redirect is also a response to client in which server sends response with status code `302`.

```
app.post('/post/save', (req, res) => {
    Post.create(req.body, (err, post) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it will be   `res.redirect('/');` not   `req.redirect('/');`

redirect user in **response**  using `res.redirect('/redirect_url_here');`

you can read more here : https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect